# Loading a Driver (Shared Lib) dynamically

Tags: android, android-ndk

For an Android App we do have several devices, which we try to access. Each User has only one of those devices. Some Devices can only be accessed with a binary NDK Shared Lib. So question is now, if it is possible to Load a driver dynamically from the Internet if, and only if, the corresponding devices us enabled?

Right now, we put the lib in the corresponding folder and all is fine. But more and more devices are coming up and need other drivers.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible but i think it would violate [Play Store Developer Policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/) which prohibits running code that does not come from Play Store. You can add all required libraries to your APK and run loadLibrary only if required feature is present on device.

Comment: If your libraries are really huge - I believe you can make use of [Expansion files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) and download what you need later.